# Will using a RYZEN cpu fix getting HAXM errors?

Tags: android

I downloaded Android Studio on a laptop that wasn't really being used (Intel cpu) but there was a HAXM error and we couldn't get rid of it no matter what we did, so soon I'm getting a new laptop (probably ryzen cpu) will that solve the issue?

We tried enabling Hyper-V, and two other virtualisation settings in the control panel, Hyper-V and the others were enabled separately and at the same time but nothing worked, we downloaded it from the Android studio SDK installer and the Intel website, still didn't work

Comment: Poor question title as you are asking about running Android Emulator on old PC. Realize that asking for opinions (which PC should I get, etc.) is off-topic here on StackOverflow, Android emulator has a requirements page: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#requirements